# DynamicCompressionModule issue with IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I am facing issue with DynamicCompressionModule and StaticCompressionModule on my Windows server 2012 R2.
DynamicCompressionModule and StaticCompressionModule are installed.
When i open my website it shows below error-

Module : DynamicCompressionModule
Notification : SendResponse 
Handler : ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit 
Error Code : 0x800700c1

It gives error even i have

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="false" doStaticCompression="false" />
```

Enable 32 bit is set to true in application pool.

If i add below tag in web.config, website starts working but i want to enable compression for my website-

```
<modules>
      <remove name="StaticCompressionModule" />
      <remove name="DynamicCompressionModule" />
</modules>
```

In Server Roles, it shows both StaticCompressionModule and DynamicCompressionModule disabled so i am not able to uncheck both to reinstall.

Can anybody provide solution for this?

Comment: In my case, it was probably adding WSUS on the server that enabled those modules. Reference: 
 https://assist.biztalk360.com/support/solutions/articles/1000191385-http-error-500-19-internal-server-error-with-error-code-0x800700c1

Comment: The link in my previous comment no longer works. I think the same info is in this article on the same site:  https://docs.biztalk360.com/docs/first-launch-issues. Search for the section "Error Type: HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error with Error Code 0x800700c1."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstalling "Performance" option worked.
Just I over looked option "Remove Roles and Features" to uninstall option.

Reference:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/how-to-remove-iis-on-windows-server-2012/

Comment: It is grayed out

Answer (score 0):

My solution was found in this article: https://support.docuware.com/en-us/knowledgebase/article/KBA-35434

It was Related to Adding WSUS to the server but the solution is Independent from external softwares.